# XSLT discrepancy with how variable is used

Tags: xslt

My question is about `xsl:variable` and the syntax for a predicate in an Xpath. I've boiled down my question to the point where this short XML can help me demonstrate:

```
<root>
  <tabular>
    <col halign="left"/>
    <col halign="right"/>
    <row>
      <cell>Some content</cell>
      <cell>Some content</cell>
    </row>
  </tabular>
</root>
```

In my application, when I am applying a template on a `cell`, I need to access the `@halign` of the corresponding `col`. In doing so, I have encountered a discrepancy between Xpath expressions that I thought should be equivalent. I would like to understand why this happens. To demonstrate, I apply the XSL at the end of this post using XSLT 1.0.

The `cell` template in my XSLT here is silly but it lays out the discrepancy I don't understand. Basically it repeatedly tries to print the `@halign` value corresponding to the second cell. First, using the `$col` variable that has value `2`. Then using `[position()=$col]`. Then using `[number($col)]`. Then simply using `[2]`, hard coded. Lastly, using a separate `$colsel` variable that was defined using a `@select` attribute.

I expect to see:

```
ancestor::tabular/col[...]/@halign
                [2]  makes  right
     [position()=2]  makes  right
        [number(2)]  makes  right
(hard 2)        [2]  makes  right
(var @select)   [2]  makes  right
```

but instead I see:

```
ancestor::tabular/col[...]/@halign
                [2]  makes  left
     [position()=2]  makes  right
        [number(2)]  makes  right
(hard 2)        [2]  makes  right
(var @select)   [2]  makes  right
```

Is anyone able to offer an explanation for why using `[$col]` behaves differently?

Here is the XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root/tabular"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tabular">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="cell"/>
</xsl:template>

<?xml version='1.0'?> <!-- As XML file -->

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root/tabular"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tabular">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="cell[2]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cell[2]">
    <xsl:variable name="col">
        <xsl:value-of select="2"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="colsel" select="2"/>
    <xsl:text>ancestor::tabular/col[...]/@halign</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>                [</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$col"/>
    <xsl:text>]  makes  </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::tabular/col[$col]/@halign"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>     [position()=</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$col"/>
    <xsl:text>]  makes  </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::tabular/col[position()=$col]/@halign"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>        [number(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$col"/>
    <xsl:text>)]  makes  </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::tabular/col[number($col)]/@halign"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>(hard 2)        [2]  makes  </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::tabular/col[2]/@halign"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>(var @select)   [</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$colsel"/>
    <xsl:text>]  makes  </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::tabular/col[$colsel]/@halign"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the variable declaration to:

```
<xsl:variable name="col" select="2"/>
```

and it will behave as you expect and select the second `col`.

You had declared the variable using [`xsl:value-of`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#value-of): `<xsl:value-of select="2"/>`, which creates a computed `text()` node.

When you use that `$col` variable by itself in a [`predicate`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-predicates), that string value `"2"` it is evaluated as `true()` in the predicate test, rather than if it were a `number()` and would then be interpreted as short-hand for `position() = 2`.

Comment: Thank you. In XSL 1.0, is there any way when not using `@select` to ensure a `xsl:variable` will be a number, not text? Other than wrapping `number()` around the variable each time I invoke it? My actual use case has something more complicated that I cannot fit into a `@select` expression. I might resort to using two `xsl:variable`s, one with the complicated creation, and the second that wraps `number()` around the value of the first. But it would be cleaner if I could just do it with one.

Comment: @alex.jordan The data type of a variable defined using a template will **always** be a *result tree fragment* - see: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#variable-values.

Answer (score 2):

Let us use a more convenient example:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <item>first</item>
    <item>second</item>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="num" select="2"/>
<xsl:variable name="str" select="string(2)"/>
<xsl:variable name="rtf">2</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <results>
        <num>
            <xsl:copy-of select="item[$num]"/>
        </num>
        <str>
            <xsl:copy-of select="item[$str]"/>
        </str>
        <rtf>
            <xsl:copy-of select="item[$rtf]"/>
        </rtf>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <num>
    <item>second</item>
  </num>
  <str>
    <item>first</item>
    <item>second</item>
  </str>
  <rtf>
    <item>first</item>
    <item>second</item>
  </rtf>
</results>
```

Now you ask why the difference in the results. The answer can be found in the XPath specification that prescribes how a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates) is to be evaluated:

> A PredicateExpr is evaluated by evaluating the Expr and converting the
> result to a boolean. If the result is a number, the result will be
> converted to true if the number is equal to the context position and
> will be converted to false otherwise; if the result is not a number,
> then the result will be converted as if by a call to the boolean
> function.

In the first instance the value of the `$num` variable is the **number** 2. Therefore the result of evaluating the expression within the predicate is a number, and the predicate will be true when the number is equal to the context position - which is only true for the `item` in the second position.

In the second instance, the value of the `$str` variable is the **string** "2". Therefore the expression within the predicate does not evaluate to a number and will be converted to boolean by doing:

```
boolean("2")
```

which returns `true()` for all `item`s, regardless of their position.

In the third instance, the value of the `$rtf` variable is a **result tree fragment**  that contains a text node that consists of the character "2". When placed in a predicate, the outcome will be similar to the previous instance: the result of evaluating the expression is not a number, and converting it to a boolean will produce a value of `true()`. Note that your:

```
<xsl:variable name="col">
    <xsl:value-of select="2"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

does exactly the same thing.

---

Note also that in XSLT 1.0 the `xsl:value-of` instruction returns the value of the first node in the selected node-set. Therefore, if we change our template to:

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <results>
        <num>
            <xsl:value-of select="item[$num]"/>
        </num>
        <str>
            <xsl:value-of select="item[$str]"/>
        </str>
        <rtf>
            <xsl:value-of select="item[$rtf]"/>
        </rtf>
    </results>
</xsl:template>
```

the result will be:

```
<results>
  <num>second</num>
  <str>first</str>
  <rtf>first</rtf>
</results>
```

but still both `item`s are selected by `item[$str]` and by `item[$rtf]`.

Comment: Thank you, I think my core misunderstanding is how `value-of` is returning a string. I was not aware of that.

Comment: Actually it's not returning a string, it's returning a text node. In a dynamically typed language with lots of conversions, the distinctions are important.